# java function being called non-stop

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2

I am using lazy scrolling on Home.xhtml. The problem is that whenever I scroll down to the bottom of the pape, Javascript calls the `getMoreStatusList` function on the getMoreStatusList.xhtml page non-stop until complier throws an index out of bounds exception.  How can I fix this?

1)Home.xhtml

```
    <h:head>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    $(document).ready(function() {

        function lastAddedLiveFunc() {
            $('div#lastPostsLoader').html('<img src="bigLoader.gif">');

            $.get("getMoreStatusList.xhtml", function(data) {
                if (data != "") {
                    //console.log('add data..');
                    $(".items").append(data);
                }
                $('div#lastPostsLoader').empty();
            });
        };

      //lastAddedLiveFunc();
      $(window).scroll(function(){

          var wintop = $(window).scrollTop(), docheight = $(document).height(), winheight = $(window).height();
          var  scrolltrigger = 0.95;

          if  ((wintop/(docheight-winheight)) > scrolltrigger) {
             //console.log('scroll bottom');
             lastAddedLiveFunc();
          }
      });
    });
    /* ]]> */
    </script>
    </h:head>

    <h:body class="thrColElsHdr">        


                <!--  -->
                <div class="items">
                    <div id="scroll_items">
                        <c:forEach var="p" items="#{statusBean.statusList}">
                            <h:form>
                                <div class="status">
                                    <c:if test="${p.statusmsg!=null}">
                                        <!--  for text status msg check-->
                                        <h:commandLink
                                            action="#{friendBean.gotoFriendProfile(p.email)}"
                                            styleClass="link">
                                            <img src="../images/profilePicture/thumb/#{p.picture}"
                                                style="height: 39px; width: 39px;" />&nbsp; <h:outputText
                                                value="#{p.statusBy}:" />
                                        </h:commandLink>

                                        <br />

                                    </c:if>


                        </c:forEach>

                    </div>
                </div>


    </h:body>
    </html>
```

2) Status Bean(this contains the getMoreStatusList function)

```
 public class StatusBean {




                public List<Status> getStatusList() {
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext()
                    .getSession(true);
            User user = (User) session.getAttribute("userdet");
            Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Status s WHERE s.email='"
                    + user.getEmail() + "' ORDER BY s.timeMillis desc",
                    Status.class);
            List<Status> results = query.getResultList();

            Collections.sort(results);
            results = results.subList(0, 5);

            session.setAttribute("statusindex", 5);
            return results;

        }

        public List<Status> getMoreStatusList() {

            System.out.println("Inside getMoreStatusList");
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext()
                    .getSession(false);
            User user = (User) session.getAttribute("userdet");
            Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Status s WHERE s.email='"
                    + user.getEmail() + "' ORDER BY s.timeMillis desc",
                    Status.class);
            List<Status> results = query.getResultList();

            Collections.sort(results);
            int index = (int) session.getAttribute("statusindex");
            System.out.println(index);
            results = results.subList(index,index+5);
            session.setAttribute("statusindex", index + 5);
            return results;

        }


    }
```

3) getMoreStatusList.xhtml

```
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>

            <c:forEach var="p" items="#{statusBean.moreStatusList}">
                <h:form>
                    <div class="status">
                        <c:if test="${p.statusmsg!=null}">
                            <!--  for text status msg check-->
                            <h:commandLink action="#{friendBean.gotoFriendProfile(p.email)}"
                                styleClass="link">
                                <img src="../images/profilePicture/thumb/#{p.picture}"
                                    style="height: 39px; width: 39px;" />&nbsp; <h:outputText
                                    value="#{p.statusBy}:" />
                            </h:commandLink>
                            <h:outputText value="#{p.statusmsg}" styleClass="textstyle1" />
                            <h:outputText value="#{p.timeMillis}"
                                style="font-size:xx-small;float:right;color:#bbbbbb;font-style: italic;">
                                <f:converter converterId="timeConverter" />

                                </div>
                            </c:forEach>
                            <br />
                            <div class="comment">
                                <p:inputText value="#{statusBean.comment.comment}"
                                    styleClass="box" />
                                <p:commandLink value="Views"
                                    action="#{statusBean.update(p.statusId)}" ajax="false"
                                    styleClass="link" />
                            </div>
                            <br />

                        </c:if>

            </c:forEach>


</h:body>

</html>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to trim down the code excerpts a little?

Comment: I have trimmed down the details of the Home.xhtml page

Comment: (Still) Way too much code here.  It's better to reduce the code to only the relevant parts. That makes it much easier to identify the problem.. In the process, you might even find the problem yourself. In any case, [so] is not a place to review complete code - we need questions to be concise so they may assist future visitors too.

Comment: Ok i am trimming it more

Comment: Try to make it the smallest possible example that demonstrates the problem. See http://sscce.org/ for some hints on the best way to present your question.

Comment: @aml - you say that the `getMoreStatusList` function is being called - so the HTML (for example) is not really adding information. Try limit it only to the components that deal with/call the `getMoreStatusList` function.

Comment: @Lix Will I trim it more, or is this okay .

Comment: You can trim it a lot more: to pick an example at random, is the line `<div id="footer">` relevant to the question? Keep deleting stuff until the problem no longer occurs: now you have the smallest example.

Comment: @CameronSkinner Now I have trimmed it more, I suppose now its okay.

Comment: no offence but such long code acts as deterrent to analyse

Comment: none taken but if you want I can make it even smaller

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that scroll is getting called multiple times as you scroll down at the bottom as your expression `wintop/(docheight-winheight)) > scrolltrigger` will be true for a pixel range as you scroll down .  You can verify it by keeping an alert on lastAddedLiveFunc() . If that is indeed the case then ,

Keep a variable like 'gettingNextScrollData' to verify if an ajax call is already in progress.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
var gettingNextScrollData = false;
    $(document).ready(function() {

        function lastAddedLiveFunc() {
            $('div#lastPostsLoader').html('<img src="bigLoader.gif">');
            gettingNextScrollData = true;
            $.get("getMoreStatusList.xhtml", function(data) {
                if (data != "") {
                    //console.log('add data..');
                    $(".items").append(data);
                }
                $('div#lastPostsLoader').empty();
             gettingNextScrollData = false; 
            });
        };

      //lastAddedLiveFunc();
      $(window).scroll(function(){
          if(gettingNextScrollData == false) {
          var wintop = $(window).scrollTop(), docheight = $(document).height(), winheight = $(window).height();
          var  scrolltrigger = 0.95;

          if  ((wintop/(docheight-winheight)) > scrolltrigger) {             
               lastAddedLiveFunc();
          }
       }
      });
    });
    /* ]]> */
    </script>
```

Comment: Actually it is supposed to run once when I reach the bottom of the page, again it is supposed to run when I reach the bottom of the page again.

Comment: We are resetting gettingNextScrollData =false at the end of first scroll in lastAddedLiveFunc. The second scroll shouldn't be a problem as it will again make a call to lastAddedLiveFunc in scroll(function).